# How can I save & extract a json object as a string inside json from PHP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to save a string which is encoded as json into another json string.
In particular, I have to be able to handle empty objects: "{}".

PHP:

```
$sVal = "{}";
$jsonString  = "{\"Var2\":\"My first var\", \"Var2\":\"My second var\", \"MyBlankObject\":\"{}\"}"

...
```

Javascript:

```
var oMyJSON = JSON.parse('< ?= $jsonString;? >');
```

I get a JSON parse error saying an unexpected `{` was found.

I can see the code in Chrome's debugger.

The brackets are simply removed and in the client side (javascript ) code, the object is replaced with the word null. That's not valid JSON.

```
,"Properties":null,
```

This causes javascript to crash.

If I try to json_encode it on the server side (PHP) I get double quotes on each side of the brackets.

```
,"Properties":""{}"",
```

I get the same thing if I just add the double quotes: ""{}""

Of course, this causes javascript to crash too.

Once in the client and I have the JSON object intact, I need to be able to extract the 'string' held in the property: `MyBlankObject` and then decode that JSON into a seperate JSON object.

Everything I've tried fails. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: PHP is for hypertext, not script, You'll  need to `echo $jsonString` somewhere in your html first. Then you can access that with javascript. Also, you shouldn't have to escape the double quotes. As is, you don't have valid JSON.

Comment: Hmm, according to [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/) that is valid, as a string. To comment on your second issue, putting quotes around `{}` makes it a string rather than an object. I think you want something like this `{"Var1":"My first var","Var2":"My second var","MyBlankObject":{}}`

Comment: **Never** build your JSON string "manually" like you do with `$jsonString  = `. It is bad practice. Always build your objects in the language you are using (PHP), and then use the built-in functions (`json_encode`) to build JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the object using PHP notation, and let `json_encode` encode it for you.

```
$phpArray = [
    'Var2' => 'My first var',
    'Var2' => 'My second var',
    'MyBlankObject' => new \stdClass
];
```

And then in the JavaScript:

```
var oMyJSON = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($phpArray); ?>');
```